# Web Scraping a site using Selenium - how 'NOT' to download an excel file

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape a website using Selenium.
https://media.japanmetaldaily.com/market/list/

I want to scrape data only for a few metals and append them in a single excel file, however, on this website the data is not actually on the webpage. When I click on the href it directly downloads the data as an excel file. The data source you get from href is forbidden.

<a href= "https://media.japanmetaldaily.com/data/KS10001.xls"onclick= "pageTracker._trackEvent('market_list', 'download', '異形棒鋼_直送_SD295_19ミリ');">

I can download multiple excel files and then manipulate them, however that completely defies the concept of web scraping. Is there a way to view the data and then write it to a dataframe in this scenario? Any help/direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The tools you need are, beautiful soup and the requests library.

Make a request to the site to get the html. Then using beautiful soup, make a list of links to the excel spreadsheets.

Then loop through the links and get them using the requests library. XLS use XML, so you can then scrape the spreadsheets using beautiful soup too.

That should be all the steps needed.

Comment: This sounds like the best solution, however, I couldn't get my head around reading the .xls file using XML part, I tried a few codes like #soup1 = (requests.get(link["href"], verify = False)), file = BeautifulSoup(soup1.text,'lxml'), but this either gets me only till response code 200 or gets into an infinite loop, could you please help me understand how this works (*Pretty new to BS4)

Comment: @mamta_rao I worked on it on my break. So far, I've downloaded all the xsl files. Now just need to get the data from them. I can add the code to my current answer if you want. Will probably add it after I've finished, but need to know what data to get, since I don't speak Japanese... Else, I'll just make some general functions where you can choose the row/column to extract data from by the title.

Comment: yeah that was my initial problem, I DO Not wish to download the xls files, I've been able to achieve that so far by translating the page to English and downloading only the files I need using Selenium, but I wanted to know if there's anyway in BS4, to Parse through the XLS file without having to download them (UPDATE : on the File Download approach os.remove() isn't working so far, trying to find a way out on that)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
from io import BytesIO

import urllib

def load_workbook_from_url(url):
    file = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    return load_workbook(filename = BytesIO(file),data_only = True)


wb=load_workbook_from_url("URL")


#get worksheets name in each sheet together in a dictionary
worksheets_tables ={}
for name in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheets_tables[name]=[]
    if bool(wb[name].tables.keys()):
        for tables in wb[name].tables.keys():        
            worksheets_tables[name].append(tables)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).